# PHP/MySQL Prepared Statements - Can one user benefit from another user's prepared query?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is there any kind of server-side optimization (like in a MySQL database) that allows one user's prepared query to benefit from another user's previously prepared query?  (The emphasis here is on possible performance improvements BETWEEN users, each query running during a separate php script.)

Example:

Query for user 1: SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE item1 = ? and item2 = ?

item 1 = x
item 2 = y

Query for user 2: SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE item1 = ? and item2 = ? (same query as above)

item 1 = y
item 2 = z

If this identical prepared query (though with different parameters each time) will only be executed once for each of these different users, is there any potential performance gain from using a prepared query?

Or would it just be better to use the real_escape_string function on items 1 and 2, and just put them right into the query.  This would avoid making two trips to the db, one to check the validity of the prepared query, and the other to actually execute the query.

I'm not all that worried about SQL injection, since with proper escaping, either method should be just as safe.  (Right?)  I'm honestly just wondering if it's worth using prepared statements if I'm not iterating through the execution of the same prepared query multiple times within the same php script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which version of MySQL you are using. See this page : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html 
If you are using MySQL before version 5.1.17, prepared statements won't be cached, and the use of MySQL query cache gives better results than the use of prepared statements, so you'd better worry about whether you are using this cache in an optimized way or not.
Otherwise, I think the answer to your question is yes, because instead of doing this twice:

1. send the request to the server
2. compile the request
3. execution plan
4. execute request
5. send result back

you would do this:

PREPARE :

1. send the request to the server
2. compile the request
3. execution plan
4. store the compiled request in memory
5. return a request identifier

EXECUTE with first series of parameters:

1. ask for execution with the identifier
2. execute
3. return result

EXECUTE another series of parameters:
 1. ask for execution with the identifier 
 2. execute 
 3. return result

(all this was translated from [this french course on prepared statements](http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-36596-requete-preparee.html))
As you see, you'll have a real performance gain if:

- you execute this request a lot
- the request is complex and takes time to compile
- the query cache is used

Comment: Wow! That's great!  Thank you!  (And I'm using a version of MySQL greater than 5.1.17)

Comment: Bonus : If you want to optimize your MySQL , you can use this script : http://mysqltuner.pl It will analyse the bunch of variables available with `show variables` for you and give good hints on what should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

you could always call a stored procedure - it's just a single call :)

```
drop procedure if exists get_user;
delimiter #

create procedure get_user
(
in p_user_id int unsigned
)
proc_main:begin
    select u.* from users u where u.user_id = p_user_id;
end proc_main#

delimiter ;

call get_user(1);
call get_user(3);
call get_user(6);
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with stored procedures.  Looks like I've got some more reading to do.  :)  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your two instances cannot share any code (without putting a lot of effort into it). Preparing the query twice should be negligible. If there are actual performance bottlenecks, the problem is probably something else.

Comment: But do you know if my MySQL db does any kind of prepared query caching that would make it go, "Oh, I just saw this prepared statement a little while ago!  I can optimize this!"  Or something like that?

Comment: And does this mean that I'm actually better off not using a prepared statement for the types of queries in my example?

Comment: @hithere: No, i do not know if MySQL caches this, but it is probably smart enough to cache stuff that is performance-relevant. I would prefer prepared statements over native queries, since it is impossible to open your doors for SQL-injections (accidentally). Security outweights performance here (in my opinion).

Comment: @elusive: Thanks for the advice.  I just did a bit more reading about sharing connection instances and it looks like way more trouble than its worth for my db working purposes.  I see what you mean.

Comment: And I guess I'll use prepared statements when I can.  If you don't mind, I have another question that's semi-related.  Do you think, for queries where I want to [SELECT * FROM Table WHERE row_id = x OR row_id = y OR row_id = z] that I'd be better off using a prepared statement where I [SELECT where row_id = ?] and use a loop to bind a different parameter to that statement each time I execute it?  Or is the OR method more efficient?

Comment: @Hithere, Don't ever ever optimize before profiling. Just because you think it will be faster, doesn't mean it will be. Let me repeat that if I wasn't clear, if you haven't profiled your app, do not optimize! Just like love before marriage, profile before optimizing!

Comment: @hithere: The `OR`-approach seems better, since it is much easier to read and is probably more efficient, since it needs less requests to the SQL-server.

Comment: @hithere, Case in point, your question, just make a simple test case to see. My gut tells me the OR would be faster since you don't have to make a round trip to the db server for each parameter. But check first!

Comment: @hithere: @Byron Whitlock is right. Profiling is definitely helpful in this case.

Comment: @Byron Whitlock and @elusive - Thanks a lot for the replies.  I'll have to give profiling a try!